# How to get an instance of IConfiguration in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I making a unittesting project to test my webapi and i need to initialize a controller the problem is that in the constructor it receive a IConfiguration that it is provide by dependency-injection and works fine.

But when I want to initialize it manually i have not way to get this instance.

I am trying to initialize it from a unittest project no inside of the same project.

The controller looks like:

```
public Controller(IConfiguration configuration) { _configuration = configuration; }
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'd probably should start from the statement that in .Net Core application you should not pass instance of `IConfiguration` to your controllers or other classes. You should use strongly typed settings injected through `IOptions<T>`. See this article for more details: [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options).

When using options pattern, you will have POCO for the settings required by a controller. This settings object is then injected into controller wrapped into `IOptions<T>`:

```
public class ControllerSettings
{
    public string Setting1 { get; set; }

    public int Setting2 { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Controller
{
    private readonly ControllerSettings _settings;

    public Controller(IOptions<ControllerSettings> options)
    {
        _settings = options.Value;
    }
}
```

Then it's pretty simple to pass any settings you want from a Unit Test. Just fill settings instance and wrap to `IOptions<T>` with any of available mocking frameworks, like [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/) or [NSubstitute](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubstitute/):

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var settings = new ControllerSettings
    {
        Setting1 = "Some Value",
        Setting2 = 123,
    };

    var options = new Mock<IOptions<ControllerSettings>>();
    options.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns(settings);

    var controller = new Controller(options.Object);

    //  ...
}
```

Sometimes it's required to use real configuration of the project, for example when developing integration test. In this case you could create instance of `ConfigurationBuilder` and fill it with the same configuration sources as in tested code:

```
IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
// Duplicate here any configuration sources you use.
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: What namespace is the ConfigurationBuilder from?

Comment: Found it, it's Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json