# Explicit Accessing Intance of Options and Passing it to Method within ConfigureServices with ASP.NET CORE API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to pass instance of IOptions to a method as parameter, like below: any idea?

```
   services.SetWaitAndRetryPolicy<CustomHttpClient>(); //how to retrieve and pass instance of IOptions<MyConfig>
```

I follow the links below and at the bottom:

[How to read AppSettings values from .json file in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-json-file-in-asp-net-core?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
    services.AddOptions();

    // Add our Config object so it can be injected
    services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"));

   services.SetWaitAndRetryPolicy<CustomHttpClient>();  //how to retrieve and pass instance of IOptions<MyConfig> 
}

 public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
    {
        public static void SetWaitAndRetryPolicy<T>(this IServiceCollection services, IOptions<MyConfig> config) where T : class
        {

        }
    }
```

[How to get an instance of IConfiguration in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017390/how-to-get-an-instance-of-iconfiguration-in-asp-net-core)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

ASP.NET CORE 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the extension method to register your `CustomHttpClient` class then you access the options within the configure method.

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static void SetWaitAndRetryPolicy<T>(this IServiceCollection services) where T : class
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<T>((sp, client) =>
        {
            var options = sp.GetService<IOptions<MyConfig>>();

            ...
        });
    }
}
```

One of the parameters to the configure action is the `IServiceProvider`. From here you can get access to any of the registered services, in this case the `IOptions<MyConfig>` settings.