# System.NullReferenceException on accessing the Base URL from the appSettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the Base URL within the appsettings.json like below

```
  "RM": {
    "BaseAddress": "https://rm-dev.abc.org/"
  },
```

With in the Class where I am trying to make a call this endpoint

```
public class InventorySearchLogic
    {
        private readonly SMContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _iconfiguration;
        public InventorySearchLogic(SMContext context, IConfiguration iconfiguration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _iconfiguration = iconfiguration;
        }

        public InventorySearchLogic(SMContext context)
        {
        } 

  public async Task<string> GetRoomID(string roomName)
        {
            //string rmID = "";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                RmRoom retRoom = new RmRoom();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_iconfiguration.GetSection("RM").GetSection("BaseAddress").Value);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
```

When debugging it throws error like `System.NullReferenceException:  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` how to access the base URL from appsettings.json

I am not sure how to use the `ConfigurationBuilder()` as I have different apSettings.json file one for each environment like `appsettings.Development.json` , `appsettings.QA.json`, `appsettings.PROD.json`

[image]

Below is my Startup

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddDbContextPool<SurplusMouseContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SMConnectionStrings"),
                  sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                  {
                      sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                  });
                });
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages()
                 .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Customers}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `BaseAddress` isn't a section. It's a property.

Comment: @gunr2171 how can I access property here?

Comment: @gunr2171 I am not sure how to use the `ConfigurationBuilder()` as I have different apSettings.json file one for each environment like `appsettings.Development.json`, `appsettings.QA.json`, `appsettings.PROD.json` how can I add the JSON file using for different instances

Comment: Try to access the value like this. _iconfiguration["RM:BaseAddress"];

Comment: @MauricioAtanache The issue is _iconfiguration is null here

Comment: Provide your Program.cs pls

Comment: @StanisalvDontsov Added Program.cs code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already injecting an `IConfiguration` in your service and saving it as `_iconfiguration`. *Assuming that's not the null value*, then simply use `.GetValue` to retrieve a value.

```
string baseAddress = _iconfiguration.GetSection("RM").GetValue<string>("BaseAddress");
```

Read more about [ASP.Net configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#getvalue)

---

Well, it seems that `_iconfiguration` is also null.

You've indicated in the comments that you're creating an instance of `InventorySearchLogic` *from a controller*, such as

```
// inside controller logic
var searchLogic = new InventorySearchLogic(_context, _iconfiguration);
```

This is the wrong approach. Instead, you should register this class as a DI service (although you should also add an interface, it's not necessary right now).

In your Startup's `ConfigureServices` method, add

```
services.AddTransient<InventorySearchLogic>();
```

Then instead of manually creating a variable of type `InventorySearchLogic`, request it though DI

```
// your controller constructor
private readonly InventorySearchLogic searchLogic;
public MyController(InventorySearchLogic searchLogic)
{
    this.searchLogic = searchLogic;
}
```

This way, InventorySearchLogic's constructor correctly gets the DI services it's looking for. You will have to move the `SMContext context`. Maybe move that to the method's parameters?

Comment: I tried as you suggested still it throws the same error because the _iconfiguration is null. I added the screenshot of the error, what could I be missing here

Comment: Are you doing anything in Program/Setup to add the configuration to DI? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55790277/dependency-injection-not-working-for-iconfiguration-c-net-core Depending on your target framework, that should be done for you by default.

Comment: I have added the `Startup` code here

Comment: Which framework are you targetting?

Comment: .NET 5.0 is the Target Frameworkusing enity framework

Comment: .Net 5 adds IConfiguration to the DI graph for you. I just tested it with an empty .Net 5 MVC website. Are you sure the `IConfiguration` in your service is `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration`? It doesn't make sense that `_iconfiguration` would be null.

Comment: I am new to this where should I check, I am passing this `public IConfiguration _iconfiguration { get; } ` from the Controller where I calling this Class `var searchLogic = new InventorySearchLogic(_context, _iconfiguration);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244669/discussion-between-gunr2171-and-user4912134).